# recipe for target main.o failed in Atmel Studio

Tags: c, temperature, atmelstudio

I am working on Atmel Studio using C Language. The program is of displaying Temperature sensed onto LCD. But When I Compile it , it give error of *recipe for target main.o failed*

please help me what to do to finish this Error??

Comment: You should [edit] your question and copy&paste the complete build command(s) with the resulting output as text to the question. There is probably a compiler error message before the message shown in the question.

Comment: It means that you have errors and could not be built (compiled and linked into the binary)

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.